# How to remove a group from a nested facet in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar

In the graph below I want to remove the empty groups. Please help me if you have an idea.

[image]

```
df = data.frame(cultivar = c("Fontane","Fontane","Fontane","Muse"), 
                 teeltnr = c("Laat","Laat","Vroeg","Vroeg"),
                 treat = c("ICM","Ref","Ref","ICM"),
                 obs = c(388, 390, 395, 346))

p = ggplot(df, aes(treat, obs, fill = treat)) + theme_classic() + 
  facet_nested(~ teeltnr + cultivar) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scales="free"`

```
library(ggh4x)
df = data.frame(cultivar = c("Fontane","Fontane","Fontane","Muse"), 
                teeltnr = c("Laat","Laat","Vroeg","Vroeg"),
                treat = c("ICM","Ref","Ref","ICM"),
                obs = c(388, 390, 395, 346))

p = ggplot(df, aes(treat, obs, fill = treat)) + theme_classic() + 
  facet_nested(~ teeltnr + cultivar, scales="free") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") 
p
```

[image]

Comment: @teunbrand  Hi, I just wanna know if I can take the top label to bottom.

facet_wrap(.~, ,strip.position="bottom") can do this but I didn't find the same method in facet_nested.